# Number Format PHP

Tags: php, number-format

Preciso Formatar o número *1000 MIL* para *100,0* ou *100.0* ou  seja, com uma casa decimal em *PHP*.

Tentei `number_format` porém retorna *1000,00* ou *1.000,00*.

Comment: Eduardo, o PHP está retornando corretamente, visto que 1000 é igual a 1000,00 ou 1.000,00. O que você pode fazer, para ESTE CASO, é dividir por 10 e aplicar a função number_format.

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado, foi falta de pensar um pouco. Tenha uma boa tarde!